# Find terminal launch command of an application

Tags: terminal, command

I've successfully installed Quartus II 13.0 on my Linux Mint 18 Sara. But I can only launch it through the Desktop shortcut. I'd like to know how to find the command I should use on the Terminal so I can delete the shortcut, and launch it via terminal, like a normal person.

I've already tried typing 'quartus' but it gives nothing but "command not found".

Comment: I know the path to the executable. Maybe I should make an alias? Still, if you have any other idea, more practical, that'd be appreciated.

Comment: How would I add the PATH? And where to?